# Should @TestPropertySource(properties = {"ticketing.profile=test"}) update the system property value automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working with Spring Boot and the com.springweb.tester package for creating tests.
I have a test class which begins like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"ticketing.profile=test"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = TicketingConfiguration.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class TicketingControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {
....
}
```

Is my understanding that calling

```
System.getProperty("ticketing.profile")
```

within one of the test methods (especially inside overridden testInit() method), will return "test" is logical?

To me it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"ticketing.profile=test"})
```

Will ***NOT*** affect the system property `ticketing.profile`.

You code should not use the system property to get the value as that means you cannot override it.

Code should use spring property fetcher which can defer to system properties if not found.

The typical approach is to set a default property in the code (or in the test as you've done) and then override it via setting the system property.